# Show only one cell UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The application works like this, its a UITableView who shows all the beacons who is on and in the same range. Then the user can chose one beacon. In the next UITableVi i want to show the beacon they have chosen, all the information about the beacon, one of these information is the RSSI who is changing value every 0.2sec. I pass the information to next page like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Tag"];

    AXABeacon *beacon = [[AXABeacon alloc] init];
    beacon = [self.sortedDevices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if([_beaconSelected.name isEqualToString:beacon.name])
    {
        UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        UILabel *uuidLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        UILabel *rssiLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
        UILabel *majorLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
        UILabel *minorLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];

        titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.name];
        uuidLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.uuidString];
        rssiLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RSSI: %@", [beacon.rssi stringValue]];
        minorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Minor: %@", beacon.minor];
        majorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Major: %@", beacon.major];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        uuidLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Here is how i have done it at the moment. This works but the problem is that this method keeps searching about beacons and when it finds another beacon it shows an empty cell. I don't want it to show another cells. I want it to show only information about the beacon they have chosen. How can i do it?

Comment: So why are you using a table view when you only have 1 item to display?

Comment: Why would you use a table view with only one cell? Why not a plain view controller with the needed labels? And why does this view controller, used to show the details of one device, have a reference to multiple devices?

Comment: The problem i have now, is the i have to show the RSSI who is changing it value every 0.2sec. The RSSI is the same as it was when the user chose a beacon from the first UITableView and keeps the same. I want the object to update its information all the time. @maddy

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use UITableView for details, I would filter beacons in this method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
   didRangeBeacons:(NSArray*)beacons
          inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region
{
    [yourMutableArray removeAllObjects];
    for (int i = 0; i < [beacons count]; i++) {
        // Compare major/minor of selected beacon with all beacons
        // and store detail information only for one specific beacon
        // to some custom object. Add this object to NSMutableArray
        // and use it as a data source for table view.
        NSString *major = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [(CLBeacon *)[beacons objectAtIndex:i] major]];
        NSString *minor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [(CLBeacon *)[beacons objectAtIndex:i] minor]];
        if ([major isEqualToString:_selectedMajor] && [minor isEqualToString:_selectedMinor]) {
            FoundBeacon *b = ....
            [yourMutableArray addObject:b];
        }
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [yourMutableArray count];
}
```

Or you can just move your "return cell;" to if block and put "return nil;" at the end, outside if block where you have "return cell" now.

Comment: Your `numberOfRowsInSection` won't even compile.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, fixed.

Comment: I did return nil where i have the return cell but i get this error ` 2015-09-22 19:27:33.858 AXASDK[3870:847430] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x148088000; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x147e55f10>; layer = <CALayer: 0x147e7dfb0>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 718}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<DetailViewController: 0x147d2e4a0>)'` @JosefRysanek

Comment: It's better to create data source properly.